# How to detect Tween.js animation finished?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, tween.js

I am using this code to animate camera in scene using tween.js
Does there a exists any done or finshed event?

```
            tween : function (target){
                var position = camera.position;
                var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(position).to(target, 1800);

                tween.onUpdate(function(){
                    camera.position.x = position.x;
                    camera.position.y = position.y;
                    camera.position.z = position.z;
                    if (android){
                        camera.lookAt(android.position)
                    }
                });
                tween.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.Out);
                tween.start(); 
            },
```

Comment: FYI for others while im lurking around tween.js posts - this snippet didn't need to set the position again in the onUpdate, it was already set by Tween at this point. It's just assigning its own values back to itself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Provide an `onComplete` function:

```
tween.onComplete(function() {
  console.log('done!')
});
```

[Docs](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md#oncomplete)

Answer (score 4):

As of April 2018, .onComplete doesn't exist in the docs. Rather you can use the `.call` function then pass a custom function.

```
   createjs.Tween.get(target).to({alpha:1}, 1000).call(handleComplete);
    function handleComplete() {
        //Tween complete
    }
```

See docs: https://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/modules/TweenJS.html

Comment: this is a different library, one is [tween.js](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/blob/master/docs/user_guide.md) the other is [tweenjs](https://www.createjs.com/docs/tweenjs/modules/TweenJS.html).